# Using the on_click option for a REVIT RPW flexform button

Tags: python, revit-api

I've been stumped by this for hours, can someone point me in the right direction?

I know the default for a button click is FlexForm.get_values, I'm trying to call my own functions.  I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

I know my mistake is in these two lines:

```
 Button('Proceed', on_click=proceed_pressed()),\
 Button('Cancel', on_click=cancel_clicked())\
```

thank you in advance.....full code below.....

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import rpw
from rpw import revit, db, ui, DB, UI
import sys
from rpw.ui.forms import FlexForm, Label, ComboBox, TextBox, TextBox, Separator, Button, CheckBox

def proceed_pressed():
    print "proceed clicked"

def cancel_clicked():
    print "canceled clicked"


components = [\
 Label('Before Labeling Outlets:'),\
 CheckBox('checkbox0', 'Audit Outlets, Zones, and Floors BEFORE writing Outlet IDs',default=True),\
 CheckBox('checkbox1', 'Send Audit results to Excel',default=False),\
 Separator(),\
 Label('Pick Outlet Labeling Options:'),\
 ComboBox('combobox2', {'Label with ROOM NUMBERS': 1, 'Label with SEQUENTIAL NUMBERS': 2}),\
 Separator(),\
 CheckBox('checkbox3', 'Include Zone Information (IDF Room)', default=True),\
 CheckBox('checkbox4', 'Include Floor Number', default=True),\
 Separator(),\
 Button('Proceed', on_click=proceed_pressed()),\
 Button('Cancel', on_click=cancel_clicked())\
 ] 

form = FlexForm('Label Outlet', components) 
form.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code will work for what you are looking for, with some easy to follow steps to build your own custom class of functions.

1. You need to create a new class that inherits from System.Windows.Window

   - why? I don't know
2. You need to add the `@staticmethod` decorator before each function

   - why? I don't know
3. You need to specify the paramter `sender` and `e`

   - why? I don't know

Sorry I can't give a proper solution.

```
clr.AddReference("PresentationFramework")
from System.Windows import Window

class ButtonClass(Window):
    @staticmethod
    def proceed_pressed(sender, e):
        print("proceed clicked")

    @staticmethod
    def cancel_clicked(sender, e):
        print("canceled clicked")


from rpw.ui.forms import FlexForm, Label, ComboBox, TextBox, TextBox, Separator, Button, CheckBox

components = [
    Label('Before Labeling Outlets:'),
    CheckBox('checkbox0', 'Audit Outlets, Zones, and Floors BEFORE writing Outlet IDs',default=True),
    CheckBox('checkbox1', 'Send Audit results to Excel',default=False),
    Separator(),
    Label('Pick Outlet Labeling Options:'),
    ComboBox('combobox2', {'Label with ROOM NUMBERS': 1, 'Label with SEQUENTIAL NUMBERS': 2}),
    Separator(),
    CheckBox('checkbox3', 'Include Zone Information (IDF Room)', default=True),
    CheckBox('checkbox4', 'Include Floor Number', default=True),
    Separator(),\
    Button('Proceed', on_click=ButtonClass.proceed_pressed),
    Button('Cancel', on_click=ButtonClass.cancel_clicked)
 ] 

form = FlexForm('Label Outlet', components) 
form.show()
```